# How to Align Text Along bottom of a Button and Icon above it?

Tags: c++, qt, button, text, icons

I want to align text along the bottom of a button and an icon above it, like these buttons in Qt:

[image]

How do I do that? (Not using the \n character because that makes it look sloppy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `QToolButton` and set `toolButtonStyle` property to `ToolButtonTextUnderIcon`